# Polynomial with roots equal to the squares of the roots of another polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Find a polynomial of degree 3 with leading coefficient 1 and roots equal to the squares of the roots of the polynomial $z^3 – 2z – 5$.

I figured that but I feel like that there is a softer, easier way
$z = \frac{1}{3} (\frac{135}{2} - \frac{(3 \sqrt{1929})}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{(\frac{1}{2} (45 + \sqrt{1929}))^{
  \frac{1}{3}}}{3^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$z(z^2-2)=5\implies z^2(z^2-2)^2=25.$$

So if $z$ is a root of the LHS, $w:=z^2$ is a root of the RHS and the requested cubic is

$$w(w-2)^2-25.$$

Comment: Crossed with MichaelBurr.

Comment: To the upvoters: I have rewritten, hopefully for better.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to find the roots explicitly, just use [Vieta's_formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Let $w_1,w_2,w_3$ be the roots of the given polynomial
$$z^3 – 2z – 5=(z-w_1)(z-w_2)(z-w_3).$$
Then
$$w_1+w_2+w_3=0,\quad w_1w_2+w_2w_3+w_3w_1=-2,\quad w_1w_2w_3=5.$$
Find
$$\begin{align}
&a_1:=w_1^2+w_2^2+w_3^2=(w_1+w_2+w_3)^2-2(w_1w_2+w_2w_3+w_3w_1)=0-2(-2)=4,\\
&a_2:=w_1^2w_2^2+w_2^2w_3^2+w_3^2w_1^2=??,\\
&a_3:=w_1^2w_2^2w_3^2=(w_1w_2w_3)^2=5^2=25.
\end{align}$$
Therefore the requested polynomial is
$$z^3-a_1z^2+a_2z-a_3.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

We first observe the following: Let $z=\sqrt{y}$, then if $\sqrt{y}^3-2\sqrt{y}-5=0,$ then $y$ is a square of a root $z$.

Unfortunately, this expression is not a polynomial since it involves square roots.  We can, however, write this expression as
$$
(y-2)\sqrt{y}-5.
$$
Now, if we multiply by the conjugate, the square roots will be squared or cancel.  In other words, we compute
$$
((y-2)\sqrt{y}-5)((y-2)\sqrt{y}+5)=y^3-4y^2+4y-25,
$$
which should have the desired roots.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$z^3-2z-5=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$$
$$z^3-2z+5=(z+z_1)(z+z_2)(z+z_3)$$

Then

$$(z^3-2z-5)(z^3-2z+5)=(z^2-z_1^2)(z^2-z_2^2)(z^2-z_3^2)$$

which, with $x=z^2$, yields the sought-after polynomial

$$x^3-4x^2+4x-25=(x-z_1^2)(x-z_2^2)(x-z_3^2)$$